# Relationship between time complexity and CPU speed k-fold

Tags: operating-system, cpu-usage

What happens to the size of the problem if we increase the speed of the processor **tenfold**?

- In linear case, then for algorithm A with time complexity `n` and
  size `s_1`, the allowable size becomes `10s_1`.
- In quadratic case, then for algorithm B with time complexity `n^2` and size `s_2`, the allowable size becomes `\sqrt{10}s_2 = 3.16s_2`.
- etc.

For the second case, if the complexity of the second algorithm is `n^2` and the size `s_2`, then  if we double CPU speed by 10 times, we would process data 10 times faster, so if we originally processed `T` size of data, now we would process same data size `s_2` in `T/10` time, which is `1/10` of time in case we increased CPU speed by 10 folds. Now, how we can relate this to the answer `3.16xs_2`?

**Problem**: can you please show how that is the case that size of algorithm B increases to `\sqrt{10}s_2 = 3.16s_2` if we increase CPU speed by 10 fold?

Comment: Can you specify what you understand and what you don't? As written, this post reads like a homework problem which is not appropriate for Stack Overflow. However if you demonstrate you have thought about the problem and where you have gotten stuck, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: @wxz. Thanks for replying. This is not a HW problem. I got it from data structure for Nell Dale et al. I am just looking to see how we got 3.16. I will edit it anyway.

Comment: @wxz. I edited it now. Hopefully this is better question now please?

Comment: I read your edit. What does "allowable size" mean in this problem?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I think this is the key to your understanding the problem.

Comment: @wxz. How size allowed changes as CPU increases per unit of time please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237223/discussion-between-wxz-and-avra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use new notation to make it easier to understand.

First, if time complexity is `n^2` and size is `x`, we can generalize and say the time it will take to finish processing is `x^2`, simply substituting `n` for `x`. Let's call the old size `x` and the new allowable size `y`.

"Allowable size" here I assume means "what is the new maximum size that can be processed in the same amount of time as before". So we can set up an equality for time (t):

`x^2 = t` with the old processor

Now with the new processor that is ten times faster, we know that the time to process that size in a perfect world would be ten times less:

`x^2 = t/10`

Isolating time we get
`10 * x^2 = t`

Now we want our new size that takes the same amount of time:

`y^2 = t`

So taking these last two equations, we know that both left sides are equal since they both equal the same time:

`10 * x^2 = y^2`

Now we just need to solve for `y`, the new size we can process with the same amount of time as before.

`\sqrt{10x^2} = y`

`\sqrt{10} * x = y`

`3.16 * x = y`

So now we know that the new "allowable size" `y` that takes the same amount of processing time is 3.16 times our old size `x`: `3.16s_2` with your notation.

Comment: Very clear answer. Thank you very much. As you clarified, the complexity of algorithm is input of size, so `n^2` will be `(x)^2` for the old CPU before increasing CPU speed 10 times, so complexity of algorithm is the time we need to process size, so `t=x^2` for the old CPU. Also, as you said, "we want our new size that takes the same amount of time y^2 = t" meaning we want to process the same size given the same amount of time and thus we have `t=y^2`.

Comment: _Also, as you said, "we want our new size that takes the same amount of time y^2 = t" meaning we want to process the same size given the same amount of time and thus we have t=y^2_ -  You mean we want to process a new size given the same amount of time. Hence `t=y^2`.

Comment: Thanks. You mean it's true that our new CPU that is 10 times faster needs only 1/10 to process s_2. So for new size, you mean any size that is less than or greater than or equal to s_2, which is y in your answer please?

Comment: _it's true that our new CPU that is 10 times faster needs only 1/10 to process s_2_ - yes. Therefore, we are able to process more data in the same amount of time as before. So in the same amount of time as before, what is the size of the data that we can now process? The size must be greater than s_2 because the CPU is faster. If the CPU were slower, then the new size that we could process in the same amount of time would be smaller than s_2.